# Bootstrap Accordion - Page jumps to bottom first then go to top issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-accordion

When I click on accordion tab, it goes to bottom of the page due to difference in amount of content and height of the content.

I used this code to send page to top, but its scroll the page to bottom first then animate it to the top, which looks weird.

```
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    window.elenow = $(this);
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(window.elenow).offset().top }, 500);
});
```

I just want to page remain still when click on accordion tab, no go to top no go to bottom, just stay where its clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent scrolling all together by changing your `href` to `href="javascript:void(0);"`

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfwvtyms/62/) that shows the example.

Comment: I cannot do that because same href links are also applied to main menu, if I change href to href="javascript:void(0);" than my menu links are stop working.

Comment: A bit of a hack, but use href="javascript:void(0);" with data-target="#you-id" on each <a> tag in the panel.  This prevents jumping, allows tabbing through works with bootstrap 3.  I never figured out why the Bootstrap example didn't jump, but this works. e.g. <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne" href="javascript:void(0);" >